# Calling Variables in another function (c++)

Tags: c++, function, variables

So I've gotta create a whole bunch of Variables for some colours for a customisable menu I'm making. I wanted to know if there was a way to call the variables from the first function into other functions (there are alot) These variables have to be used in over 100 locations across about 10 different functions and I really don't want to redefine all the sh*t over again every single time. (Looks messy and is a pain if I need to make changes. Heres my Menu Colour Function

```
Color MenuColor(int MenuAlpha_Main)
{
    Color Theme;
    Color Basic = Color(c_config::get().menu_color_r, c_config::get().menu_color_g, c_config::get().menu_color_b, MenuAlpha_Main);
    Color Background = Color(c_config::get().menu_background_r, c_config::get().menu_background_g, c_config::get().menu_background_b, MenuAlpha_Main);
    Color MiscSelectedTab_Colour = Color(c_config::get().MiscSelectedTab_r, c_config::get().MiscSelectedTab_g, c_config::get().MiscSelectedTab_b, MenuAlpha_Main);
    Color MiscSelectedTab_Highlight_Colour = Color(c_config::get().MiscSelectedTab_Highlight_r, c_config::get().MiscSelectedTab_Highlight_g, c_config::get().MiscSelectedTab_Highlight_b, MenuAlpha_Main);
    Color MiscUnSelectedTab_Colour = Color(c_config::get().MiscUnSelectedTab_r, c_config::get().MiscUnSelectedTab_g, c_config::get().MiscUnSelectedTab_b, MenuAlpha_Main);
    Color MiscUnSelectedTab_Highlight_Colour = Color(c_config::get().MiscUnSelectedTab_Highlight_r, c_config::get().MiscUnSelectedTab_Highlight_g, c_config::get().MiscUnSelectedTab_Highlight_b, MenuAlpha_Main);

    /////rainbow sync//////
    static unsigned int last_time;
    last_time = GetTickCount();
    Color rainbow;
    rainbow.FromHSV(fmod(last_time * 0.0002f, 1.f), 1.f, 0.5f);
    //////////////////////

    // Oh fuck, time for the customizable shit
    Color MiscSelectedTab;
    Color MiscSelectedTab_Highlight;
    Color MiscUnSelectedTab;
    Color MiscUnSelectedTab_Highlight;


    if (c_config::get().menu_colour_style == 0) {
        Theme = Basic; //Normal Style
    }
    else if (c_config::get().menu_colour_style == 1) {
        Theme = rainbow; //Rainbow
    }
    else if (c_config::get().menu_colour_style == 2) {
        //This shit is done below
    }
    return Theme;

    if (c_config::get().menu_colour_style == 0 || c_config::get().menu_colour_style == 0 && !c_config::get().fullmenuhighlight) {
        MiscSelectedTab = Background;
        MiscSelectedTab_Highlight = Theme;
        MiscUnSelectedTab = Background;
        MiscUnSelectedTab_Highlight = Theme;
    }
    else if (c_config::get().menu_colour_style == 0 || c_config::get().menu_colour_style == 0 && c_config::get().fullmenuhighlight) {
        MiscSelectedTab = Theme;
        MiscSelectedTab_Highlight = Theme;
        MiscUnSelectedTab = Theme;
        MiscUnSelectedTab_Highlight = Theme;
    }                             // MISC SUBTAB (Misc/Colours)
    else if (c_config::get().menu_colour_style == 2) {
        MiscSelectedTab = MiscSelectedTab_Colour;
        MiscSelectedTab_Highlight = MiscSelectedTab_Highlight_Colour;
        MiscUnSelectedTab = MiscUnSelectedTab_Colour;
        MiscUnSelectedTab_Highlight = MiscUnSelectedTab_Highlight_Colour;
    }

    return MiscSelectedTab;
    return MiscSelectedTab_Highlight;
    return MiscUnSelectedTab;
    return MiscUnSelectedTab_Highlight;
}
```

I'm still fairly fresh to cpp so please don't judge. And the return values would need to be referenced in a function like this

```
void miscsubtab(int& current_players_esp_subtab, int tab_amount, Vector _pos, int MenuAlpha_Main)
{
    int in_sizew_esp_player_subtabs = GroupBoxSize_Width - 8;
    static std::string ESP_Player_SubTabs_Names[2] = { "Misc", "Colours" };
    for (int i = 0; i < tab_amount; i++)
    {
        RECT text_size2 = g_pSurface->GetTextSizeRect(Globals::SmallText, ESP_Player_SubTabs_Names[i].c_str());
        int tab_area[4] = {
            _pos.x + 9 + (i * (in_sizew_esp_player_subtabs / tab_amount)), _pos.y + 52 + 5,
            (in_sizew_esp_player_subtabs / tab_amount), 20
        };
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) && g_pSurface->MouseInRegion(tab_area[0], tab_area[1], tab_area[2],
            tab_area[3]))
            current_players_esp_subtab = i;
        if (current_players_esp_subtab == i)
        {
            g_pSurface->FilledRect(tab_area[0], tab_area[1], tab_area[2], tab_area[3], MiscSelectedTab); //HERE
            g_pSurface->FilledRect(tab_area[0], tab_area[1] + tab_area[3], tab_area[2], 3, MiscSelectedTab_Highlight); //HERE

            g_pSurface->DrawT(tab_area[0] + (((in_sizew_esp_player_subtabs / tab_amount) / 2) - (text_size2.right / 2)),
                tab_area[1] + (tab_area[3] / 2) - (text_size2.bottom / 2),
                Color(143, 143, 143, MenuAlpha_Main), Globals::SmallText, false,
                ESP_Player_SubTabs_Names[i].c_str());
        }
        else
        {
            g_pSurface->FilledRect(tab_area[0], tab_area[1], tab_area[2], tab_area[3], MiscUnSelectedTab); //HERE
            g_pSurface->FilledRect(tab_area[0], tab_area[1] + tab_area[3], tab_area[2], 3, MiscUnSelectedTab_Highlight); //HERE
            g_pSurface->DrawT(tab_area[0] + (((in_sizew_esp_player_subtabs / tab_amount) / 2) - (text_size2.right / 2)),
                tab_area[1] + (tab_area[3] / 2) - (text_size2.bottom / 2),
                Color(143, 143, 143, MenuAlpha_Main), Globals::SmallText, false,
                ESP_Player_SubTabs_Names[i].c_str());
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks -Kenny

Comment: Use classes or structures, and make those member variables?

Comment: Yes, simply put all variable into logical structures and reuse them

Answer (score 0):

You can define a seperate Theme struct for it and use all colors from a Theme variable.

```
class Theme {
public:
enum Style {BASIC, RAINBOW, CUSTOM};

Style style;
Color MiscSelectedTab;
Color MiscSelectedTab_Highlight;
Color MiscUnSelectedTab;
Color MiscUnSelectedTab_Highlight;
}

Theme MenuColor(int MenuAlpha_Main)
{
Theme theme;
...
if (c_config::get().menu_colour_style == 0) {
    theme.style = Theme::BASIC; //Normal Style
}
else if (c_config::get().menu_colour_style == 1) {
    theme.style = Theme::RAINBOW; //Rainbow
}
else if (c_config::get().menu_colour_style == 2) {
    theme.style = Theme::CUSTOM;
    //This shit is done below
}
....
return theme;
}
```

...

```
Theme myTheme = MenuColor(5);

myTheme.MiscSelectedTab;
myTheme.MiscSelectedTab_Highlight;
myTheme.MiscUnSelectedTab;
myTheme.MiscUnSelectedTab_Highlight;
```